# shaking while driving not felt in steering column new vehicle

Tags: vw, driving

Brand new VW Atlas. driving fine to work. coming home part way through the drive started to shake/shimmy significantly but not felt in steering wheel   pulled over checked tires, absolutely nothing  resume driving and shaking resumes.  It is cold weather, however, no snow packed in the rims or anything. No loud noises  strictly the shaking.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the shake/shimmy particular to any speed? Does it quiet down at certain speeds? Does it go away any after the vehicle has been driven for a while? I'd suggest you check the rear tires really closely for one with a bulge or where the tread looks askew. Could be a new tire has slipped a belt or has an air bubble in it. I'd suggest it's not in the front since you don't feel it in the steering wheel. That doesn't mean to *not* check it, but my gut tells me it's not there.

Comment: I would check the sway bar bushings and end links for play.